# How to set different background, input and output colors

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

I want to create a notebook where the background is one color, the input cells are another color, and the output cells are white. I have tried messing around with Option Inspector and creating a custom style sheet, but it all cases I cannot get the background and the input cells to have a different color. Any thoughts?

Comment: You do not do this via the options inspector. Immediately above options inspector is Edit Stylesheet. That is what you need. If you search on this site there is ample information that covers this -- this is almost certainly a duplicate. For example for "Input" add `Background->RGBColor[1,1,0]`,; for "Notebook" add  `Background->RGBColor[1,1,0]`; for "Output" add `Background->GrayLevel[1]`

Comment: Thanks Mike, but when I do this there is no "Notebook" style to choose from. I can choose "All" but that messes with the "Input" background too.

Comment: In order assure that @MikeHoneychurch sees your comment meant for him, you need to address it as I just did.  You, PatrickS, automatically receive all comments to your question, but he does not.

Comment: Okay, thanks @bbgodfrey

Comment: @bbgodfrey - Does that comment trick work for all names or only names that don't have spaces. I frequently find that my "@xxx" disappears after entering a comment and don't understand the mechanism.

Comment: @JackLaVigne  The site deletes the `@` in front of the names of people who would automatically receive the comment.  For instance, if I tried to enter PatrickS with an ampersand, the ampersand would be deleted.  Also, the site will accept only one person addressed with an ampersand per comment.  To answer your specific question, when I typed `@` and then the first letter of your site name, the site immediately suggested your whole name, which I simply clicked on.  In general, I notice that the site deletes blanks from names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by editing the private stylesheet (see other SE questions about this):

[image]

which gives:

[image]

or evaluate this, which can be inferred from other questions on this site about style sheeting:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], Background -> GrayLevel[0.5]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], Background -> RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Output"], Background -> GrayLevel[1]]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
 ]
```