# How can I change the background color of input and output cells

Tags: notebooks

I would like to set automatically the background colour of input and output cells in any newly open notebook.

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Please search the site for the keyword "Stylesheet". This thread might be useful, amongst others: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99505/131 (this might be duplicate, if not, please let us what differentiates your question).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the font changing question. For one thing the OP wants to have a new style to be used in future notebooks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it.

1. Open a private style sheet for the notebook in question by choosing Edit Stylesheet from the Format menu.
2. In the private style sheet window, select the cell style you want to change, say Input. An input cell template will appear in the style sheet window.
3. Select the cell template.
4. Choose the background color you want from the Background Color sub-menu of the Format menu. The background color of the template cell and all the corresponding cell in your notebook will display the new backgrond.
5. Repeat 2 through 4 for each cell style you want to change.
6. To save this change in a new style that you can apply to any notebook you open, click on the Install Stylesheet... button at right of the toolbar in the private style sheet window and follow the directions give for the dialog that appears. The new style will appear in Stylesheet sub-menu of the Format menu when you start a new *Mathematica* session.

[image: notebook]

[image: stylesheet]

[image: dialog]