# Changing Text cell color

Tags: style

What can I set so that whenever I create a text cell, everything I enter into the text cell, whether plain text or some mathematical notation (Ctrl+9 on the Macintosh) is in a particular color I would like to choose?

Comment: The color of all text can be set by using Option Inspector to specify FontColor.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for this answer, but this sets all the colors ( I selected Blue ) to Blue. Even the input cell color is now blue, which I wanted to remain the usual black color.

Comment: Indeed, so.  That is what I meant by "color of all text "  Perhaps, progress can be made by means of a style sheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new style "BlueText" derived from the "Text" style.

[image: blue_text]

#### Update

This a partial answer to an issue raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

I will work up a step by step explanation as soon as I can find the time. Might be a day or two. Meanwhile, you might look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100579/3066) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28299/). Also, you might search this site for "stylesheet". BTW the code I show in the private stylesheet needs to be entered with the cell opened to raw form; i.e., select the cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to get that view. Press the same key combo again to go back to normal display.

Comment: This looks like a possible excellent introduction to forming my own stylesheet. Are you using Mathematica 11.1.1? I opened a new notebook, saved it as BlueNotebook.nb. I selected the Format->Edit Stylesheet menu and entered BlueText in the "Enter a style menu" block. Then I entered the code you suggested. But then I don't know where those menus came from or what I am to do next. Can you add further explanation. I appreciate this answer.

Comment: @David. I have written the step-by-step tutorial on creating a stylesheet. You can find it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153102/3066)

Comment: Outstanding! :-)  Your help over the years has been at a really exceptional level and have helped me to learn so much about Mathematica. Thanks again.