# Want a BlockQuote style in my notebooks

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet

I would like to format a cell as a block quote. Similar to here on stackoverflow:

> This is a blockquote.

I think there is no such default style in Mathematica version 11.2.

Does anyone have or know how to create a block quote style which will augment the default notebook style?

Comment: How exactly should it behave/look like?

Comment: I guess text should be indented and has a background color. I know everyone has a different expectation, but I was hoping that there is already something out there. Virtually all authoring tools offer a default style: LaTeX, Markdown, reStructuredText, Html, LibreOffice Writer, MS Word, ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought this was a good idea, so I added a **BlockQuote** style to the custom stylesheet I normally use. That is, I added the cell

```
Cell[StyleData["BlockQuote"],
  CellMargins->{{90, 3.}, {4., 4.}},
  MenuSortingValue->1540]
```

You can do the same.

If you don't already have a custom stylesheet, do the following:

1. Open any new notebook in the default style.
2. Choose **Edit Stylesheet...** from the **Format** menu.
3. Type **BlockQuote** into the input field at the top of the stylesheet template. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.
4. Select the **BlockQuote** cell that appears and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
5. Select the `Cell` expression and paste the above code over it.
6. type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
7. I didn't want a background color so I didn't set one. You can set one at this point by selecting the **BlockQuote** cell and giving it a background color using the **Format** menu.
8. Click on the **Install Stylesheet...** button at top-right of the stylesheet template and install the new stylesheet.

#### Update

This update addresses a further question asked by the OP in a comment below.

The easiest way, I think, is to open a new notebook, give it your custom stylesheet as its stylesheet, choose **Edit Stylesheet...** from the **Format** menu, make your edits and then reinstall the stylesheet.

The installation dialog will insist that you give the edited stylesheet a name different from its current name. For how to deal with that read the notes to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153103/3066)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I edit the stylesheet after I have installed it?

Comment: @Hotschke. I have updated my answer to address the issue of editing.

Comment: I see. Thanks also for the link. IMHO this is not really convenient. People at WR seem to have different workflows.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few built-in styles that might be useful:

- `"CodeText"`, which is similar to normal text, except that it's gray instead of black, and leaves a bit more space between it and the cell above and a bit less below.
- `"SmallText"`, which is similar to normal text, except that the font is a bit smaller.
- `"ItemParagraph"`, which is similar to normal text, but indented a bit more.  There are also "sub" variants of these that indent more and decrease the font size a bit.

If you don't use a lot of different styles, I fing the easiest way to use these is to use **Format > Style > Other** since it has a keyboard shortcut and remembers the last style used.